# Android ActionBar Tab issues with versions and Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm developing an application and do not want to be backward compatible lower than 4.2. I just want to add an Actionbar with Tabs and ViewPager enabled. But there are issues with the ActionBar.

I followed the tutorial below which is using the v4 support library: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

But android.app.ActionBar is not working with the v4 support library. According to other descriptions one should add the support library v7 which contains  android.support.v7.app.ActionBar. I did not have the v7 support library included so I've tried following the Android manual to add the v7 library support:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

**MainActivity.java includes**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; // does not exist!!!
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ...
}
```

When I use "import android.app.ActionBar" I get following error message: "error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) in TabListener"

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/core-2.3.0.jar', 'libs/android-integration-2.3.0-supportv4.jar')
}
```

But I also get the message that the ActionBar was not found.

Can somebody tell me how I can add an ActionBar with Tabs and ViewPager? It does not have to be backwards compatible lower then 4.2.

These support libraries and version differencies do get me confused and there's no real documentation based on the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the library if its exist in android studio files 
Android Sutdio Folder > sdk > extras > android > support 
from there you should find the libraries folders for example 
V4 & v7 & v13 ..

if you dont find it then install the extra from Android Studio

Android Studion IDE -> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> then From Extras choose the support Library.

Also to run the Viewpager tabs with action bar you can use the android-support-v4 .

Another Solution from Android Sutdio you can use the Create New Project and choose the Blank activity template which should provie a template for navigation and tabs and viewpager .

Comment: hi eshbeata, thanks for your message. i have following: /opt/android-studio/sdk/extras/android/support/v7 and in the libs folder in there I have following: android-support-v4.jar  android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. In the main directory I have appcompat  gridlayout  mediarouter. No ActionBar directory. I'm currently using android-support-v4. The problem is that the normal ActionBar is not working with the android-support-v4.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the new project and the template for the viewpager. I'm currently looking in to that and it seems one has to use the v13 FragmentPagerAdapter and v4 ViewPager. Wow, I just hope Google isn't proceeding with this compatibility horror. It's extremely difficult to find out which version has to be used for what.

Comment: After creating a new project with the tab navigation auto created I could see how to do it and what versions of libraries are used.